# LNK2001: unresolved external symbol - Reading a zip file with zlib

Tags: c++, zlib

I'm just trying to test out zlib by reading a file, but I'm encountering some trouble.  Here is my code

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "contrib\minizip\unzip.h"


unzFile readUnzip(char *filename)
{
    unzFile myFile=unzOpen(filename);

    return myFile;
}

int main () {

    unzFile myFile=readUnzip("filepath");

}
```

An error occurs that is
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _unzOpen
I'm not sure why this is, I am including the correct header file aren't I?

Comment: Are you linking to the zlib library when you link?

Comment: this is not a compilation error, but a linker one... you have to add a library to link with (#include a header is not enough)

Comment: You also need to link the relevant library files. Look at the documentation of the library that you are using.

Comment: what your code requires is not zlib, it requires minizip instead. Minizip is a contributional part of zlib, but not included in the static library artefact.